# CSS columns huge blank space at bottom

Tags: css, margin, multiple-columns

I have a image gallery using CSS-Columns, but at the bottom of the column wrapper there is always a huge blank space. I have read that setting display: block to elements can fix this, but it doesn't make any difference in this case.

The html structure is:

```
<div id='hodgePodge'>

  <a href="joatmos.pdf" target="blank">
  <div class="projectTile">
    <img class = 'hodgeimg' src = 'imagelink' alt="Hodge Image">
    <div class="projectHoverBg"></div>
    <div class="aboutProject">
      <h2>Description</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  </a>

  <div class="projectTile">
    <img class = 'hodgeimg' src = 'imagelink' alt="Hodge Image">
    <div class="projectHoverBg"></div>
    <div class="aboutProject">
      <h2>Description</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

    etc......
</div>
```

and the CSS is:

```
#hodgePodge
    margin-top menu-height
    width 100%
    padding-bottom -30px
    columns 2
    column-gap 0
    background accent-col
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
    column-break-inside:avoid;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    img
        width 100%
        display block
    .projectTile
        overflow hidden
        position relative
        .projectHoverBg
            width 100%
            height 100%
            background black
            opacity: 0
            position absolute
            top 0
            left 0
            z-index 2
        .aboutProject
            position absolute
            padding 0 0 0 30px
            bottom 0
            width 100%
            z-index 3
```

The problem can be seen here http://www.isjackwild.com/hodge.html

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: try adding in `min-height`

Comment: it must have something to do with heights or the javascript you are using, because if you add a new element or delete an existing one, everything goes into place

Comment: Where have you read it could be fixed with a `display: block;` ? I'm running into the same problem and I can't find any documentation anywhere on this.